# geom_dotplot in rpy2?

Tags: python, ggplot2, rpy2

When I try to use `gplot2.geom_dotplot` I get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'geom_dotplot'
```

Does this function have a different name in Rpy2? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mapping of that function is just missing. This is a bug with rpy2. The fix will in the repository shortly (will be released with version 2.3.4).

In the meantime a workaround can be to add the following to your code.:

```
from rpy2.robjects.lib import ggplot2

class GeomDotplot(ggplot2.Geom):
    _constructor = ggplot2.ggplot2_env['geom_dotplot']
ggplot2.geom_dotplot = GeomDotplot.new
```